# Sending data with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a website that should send a name to a python script (on a third-party website) when a button is pressed. This python script will then make the name uppercase and return it back to the website.

Right now an XMLHttpRequest is correctly being sent when the button is pressed, but I'm unsure how I correctly send the data with the XMLHttpRequest, and then how this data is accessed in the python script.

XMLHttpRequest:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", 
    function() {
        var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        myRequest.open('GET', 'https://example.com/');

        myRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { 
            if (myRequest.readyState === 4) {
                alert(myRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
        myRequest.send("Bob"});
    }
);
```

Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from requests import request

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello_world():
    return jsonify(name = (name_sent_by_XMLHttpRequest).upper()) # Should return "BOB"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: i guess this is some kind of test/task from a school/university as it makes no sense to make an api call to make something upper case

Comment: It's not for school / university. I'm not actually using it to make something uppercase, but it's a good example without going into a lot of detail.

Comment: [Using XMLHttpRequest - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about javascripts' XMLHTTPRequest but at some point, you need to send the `name` to the python server, right? HOW to do that is up to you, but a GET based option:

GET request with args: `https://example.com/?name=your_name_goes_here`

in your flask app, the function listening on route `"/"` will now have access to that arg, something like

`name = request.args.get('name', '')`

then you can uppercase() it, and return it in some format - probably XML ?

`return Response(my_xml, mimetype='text/xml')`

Update based on your comment: usually in a flask function, you would use the flask `request` object to get your URL parameters. In your example, you're importing the `requests` module as `request`, not using it, but clobbering the `flask.request` namesspace. Change your imports to something like this, and it should work normally:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import requests
```

Comment: This causes an issue with `request` as it says `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'`

Comment: @Lana - looks like you're over writing the flask request name space with the requests module by importing it `as request`. I updated my answer with a work around.